# Captura F5 y Ejecutar Funcion

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax

Estoy realizando un proyecto con `jQuery (Ajax y Json especificamente)`, en donde los datos agrego a mi documento con `JavaScript` por la cual las paginas no tienen url, y si hago `F5` se me borran todos lo datos, intento capturar el `F5` y cargarlos nuevamente lo datos, pero solo funciona cuando hay un `Alert` en medio

```js
var vta = 0;
function capturarf5(e) {
    //alert("f5");
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code === 116) {
        if (vta === 1)
            $("#contenedor").load("Lista");
    }
}
document.onkeydown = capturarf5;
```

¿Álguna forma de re-cargar los datos?

Comment: Guárdalos en el localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo almacenar los datos con web Storage, es decir datos que quedarian guardados en el browser del usuario.
Luego recuperas los datos, si es que los hay.

La verdad que es muy sencillo, solo tienes que guardar tu objeto como un JSON y con un alias, y cuando quieres recuperarlo simplemente llamas al storage con el alias y listo.

Para guardar:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('usuario',$('#txtUsuario').val());
```

Para recuperarlo

```
$('#txtUsuario').val() = sessionStorage.getItem('usuario');
```

Aquí tienes mas sobre esto

https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webstorage.asp